# Learning curve - train error increases test error decreases

Tags: cross-validation, train

I get a learning curve as below
[image]

Y - R2
what does it mean? Do I need to just add data? Or the problem in algoritm?
The dataset has 1 000 rows and 10 categorical and 3 numeric variables.
I used `xgboost`
Strategy of cross validation

```
ShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=0.20)
```

Comment: Suggestion : lower your learning rate (eta) and rebuild, see if the test error starts to go down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing a *very* typical learning curve where as you add more trees to the GBM, your model is learning too much of the noise in the training set, and that doesn't help predicting the test set. In other words, your model suffers from overfitting. Pick any book/tutorial/course/blog on machine learning and you will find lots of discussion of this issue.

One such place is,

http://cs229.stanford.edu/materials.html